# Update Javascript libraries when deploying a web application to Windows Azure

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, azure, mercurial

I have an MVC4 web application that uses **jquery** and some other libs (**jquery-ui** in particular).

Yesterday I decided to update all the packages via **NuGet** package manager; my web application worked correctly on my local machine, but when I deployed it to my azure website a javascript error popped out in my browser (it was related to jquery-ui library, something like "*$browser is not a function*").

I searched the web and found out that the cause of this error was that I was still using an old version of jquery. It seems that deploy process didn't publish the new version of the js libraries even if they have been updated in local project.

I solved the problem connecting via RDP to the Azure machine, deleting the contents of "Scripts" folder and deploying again, but I'm wondering if there's a way to "force" script/libraries update when deploying to Azure.

---

*Edit 1*: I'm developing with Visual Studio 2012, using Mercurial as source control provider

---

*Edit 2*: I'm deploying to Azure Web Sites

Comment: Did you do clean checkout on your machine?

Comment: @Garath What do you mean with 'clean checkout'? Sorry, but I'm not familiar with the term: do you mean a checkout from my source control provider (by the way it's Mercurial)?

Comment: I do know how you deploy to Azure. This change could take place in following reasons: Azure install wrong nuget package (less probable, because it does not change scripts as I remember) or you have something wrong in you source control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, in your future questions clearly indicate what type of Azure Service do you use. An MVC4 web application can be deployed to 3 different type of services: Azure Web Sites, Azure Cloud Service, Azure Virtual Machine!

Since you are talking about RDP, the viable options are Cloud Service or Virtual Machine. But then you say

> I solved the problem connecting via RDP to the Azure machine, deleting
>   the contents of "Scripts" folder and deploying again, but I'm
>   wondering if there's a way to "force" script/libraries update when
>   deploying to Azure.

Now the question is how you do deploy to Windows Azure? Is it via Visual Studio's `Publish` feature to Azure Cloud Service. Is it Visual Studio's `Package` feature and then using any other method of deployment (upload the package from the portal, use Azure PowerShell cmdlets, or use third party tool to deploy the package)? Is it integration with Mercurial and deployment is done automatically when you check-in?

Any any case, the issue you face is a mixture of NuGET failing to do real clean update of everything. Browser caching - especially for local development - IE caches all the scripts, CSS and images and it is hard to say (without explicitly deleting all locally cached files) which script are you actually using. Simple version control issue - keeping old and new scripts.

When you do a JS/CSS updates I strongly advise all the customers to first delete all browser's cache (`crtl`+`shift`+`del` - works for all browsers) before testing locally.

I highly doubt that if you use a Cloud Service, RDP-ing and deleting anything in the `sitesroot` folder will help you when you redeploy. What you do in the `ROLEROOT` drive (usually `E:`, sometimes `F:` drive) is dropped of/forgotten when you `re-deploy` regardless of the re-deploy method you use: in-place-upgrade or full re-deploy. So what you did is actually creating new package and re-deploying your new package.

The fact that you deleted some folder has no effect on your `re-deploy` action.